# Data leakage if I add prediction as feature?

Tags: machine-learning, data-leakage

I have a training set and a test set.
Let's assume the following:

1. I train random forest on the training set
2. I make prediction on training set and test set
3. Then I add those prediction as features back into the training set and the test set
4. Now I train another random forest but on the training set from step 3
5. Finally I make prediction on the test set from step 3 with the model from step 4.

Would it count as data leakage when I use prediction from step 2 as feature to the model in step 4-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not. It’s a special case of *stacking* in general and used widely in practice, Especially with different methods one after another.

In typical [stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#/Stacking) you use several models and a second level on top of these as a meta model. The meta model uses predictions from 1st level models and learns on top of them. You've just one model in your first level and a *combiner* in the second level with additional features (i.e. base features again). This is similar (not the same) to adding layers to neural networks.

I didn't encounter your specific case (i.e. RF after RF), but I recall several other problems first using a typical baseline method and then fit another model on predictions/residuals using extra features to boost it.

TL;DR This is not data leakage.

Comment: Do you have any reference to this being a special case of stacking. I would like to read something about this or see the results of this being used.

Comment: I've added some more comments.